# Send Json Request in POST Method

Tags: java, rest, http-post, ibm-bpm

I have a JSON string which is coming from Queue. I need to send it as request parameter to create a case in BPM via REST.
Rest Service Input- request(String)
Therefore I form the below and try to call the rest service

```
    Request- {\"request\":\"{'hits' : [{'id' : '50', 'version' : 1}]}\"}

When i use the uri="https://localhost:9044/rest/bpm/wle/v1/service/RISKM%40CreateCase?action=start&params=%7B%22request%22%3A%22%7B+%5C%22hits%5C%22+%3A+%5B+%7B+%5C%22id%5C%22+%3A+%5C%2250%5C%22%2C+%5C%22version%5C%22+%3A+1%7D%5D%7D%22%7D&createTask=false&parts=all";
```

Above works fine

but when i use the below

```
uri="https://localhost:9044/rest/bpm/wle/v1/service/RISKM@CreateCase?action=start&createTask=false&parts=all&params={\"request\":\"{'hits' : [{'id' : '50', 'version' : 1}]}\"}";
```

It gives the error:-
Error----HTTP Version Not Supported

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Response 500
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:89)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:118)
    at com.sita.createCase.Restcall2.readContent(Restcall2.java:193)
    at com.sita.createCase.Restcall2.makeRestCall(Restcall2.java:162)
    at com.sita.createCase.Restcall2.CallRest(Restcall2.java:94)
    at com.sita.createCase.Restcall2.main(Restcall2.java:216)
```

If i copy the same url in postman it work fine in both the case.
Need help on how can i send this request from Java Client.
Also how to stringify the json string?

Below is the Java Client  Code

```
       HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
            connection.connect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you  must Send Every Parameters as A Single Parameter.
Can't Send An Object  As A Parameter In Address.
If You Want To Send An Object, Must Send It As A Body.
In This Case You Should Write:

> id=50&version=1

instead Of :

> params={"request":"{'hits' : [{'id' : '50', 'version' : 1}]}"}"

And Handle Validation Of Objects In Backend.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have sent this in the body and it worked.